# Problem while returning a ResponseEntity<byte[]> from REST API. Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When, I return `ResponseEntity<byte[]>(new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(sb.toString().getBytes(), headers, HttpStatus.OK))` from REST API, it takes about 6 seconds but when I return `responseEntity.getBody()`, it takes about 1 seconds. How ?

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = configTemplateService.getConfigTemplateExample(type);
// This need very long time
return responseEntity;
```

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = configTemplateService.getConfigTemplateExample(type);
// This need less time
return responseEntity.getBody();
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? that method that is calling both of these?

Answer (score 0):

Data type of `responseEntity.getBody()` is `String` (1).

Data type of `responseEntity` is binary data (2) including `Body` and another parts those are not `Body` (such as `Header`).

**(2) = (1) + (another parts)**

therefore, **(2) > (1)**

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance you are only sending the body , which is light ( i.e has less size ) , so the transfer of data is fast

but in the seconde instance the data you are sending is heavy (i.e is larger in size) hence the transfer takes more time.